# Custom post types and permalinks : What a mess !

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I know that's a common problem with the custom-post-types, but I'm stuck there.  I created a custom-post-type named 'cpt_soins'. I have no page with similar name (singular/plural)...

I tried with
 `'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'nos-soins-et-services');`

when I registered my custom post type in order to display a more pretty url than "/?cpt_soins=soins-visage-a-la-rose"... But I'm stuck with a 404 error.

I want this ugly permalink: "http://localhost:8888/wordpress/?cpt_soins=soins-visage-a-la-rose" ---> transformed into: "http://localhost:8888/wordpress/nos-soins-et-services/soins-visage-a-la-rose"

I know i can use the "add_rewrite_rule() with regex". But I did'nt get working. Could you give me the code please for the functions.php in order to get my permalink ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

`'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'nos-soins-et-services');`

To this:

`'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'nos-soins-et-services', 'with_front' => true);`

Comment: I tried already front with true, but it did'nt worked. See my edited questions, I got it ! Everything rocks now...

Comment: This would work but you may have written your code wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need to flush the rewrite rules after changing the 'rewrite' arg. This can be done most easily by accessing WP Admin -> Settings -> Permalinks.

Comment: I have already force the flush, but without success (manually and within the code...)

Comment: I've recently heard about a super-flush: Switch to default permalinks, save, then switch back to your chosen permalink structure. Don't know if it helps.

Comment: Also, it would be useful if you posted the entire post type definition (without the labels, though).

Comment: I already tried this. Without success...

Answer (score 1):

I've got it ! I used the plugin "Custom Post Type UI" in order to register my custom-post-type. I was stucked with my permalinks problems so I decided to redo everything manually without plugin. So I took the code from the codex to register my custom-pot-type and my taxonomies. I create a page template for displaying my custom-post-type, create some article under my custom post-type, and so on. Now everything work like a charm (category with my taxonomies and my articles asides my custom-post-types and top of that : the pretty permalinks).

I left the **'rewrite' => true**. Nothing to do anymore... Don't bother with the permalinks. Just the for the fun I tried with **'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'my-word-for-my-permalink'), It works as well !**

Don't forget to flush the permalinks manually and within your register function for cpt (at least once) in the functions.php...

Does anybody got some similar problem with the plugin "Custom Post Type UI" ?
Which plugin do you use for create/manage your custom-post-types ?

Thanks everybody and have fun with your custom-post-types ! :-)

Comment: Your better off just creating them using the code from the codex. Most of the custom post type plugins are bloated and contain more than you need.

Comment: You could always use this http://themergency.com/generators/wordpress-custom-post-types/

Comment: @xLRDxREVENGEx That is very cool.

Answer (score 1):

Your pretty URL is not working because you have not introduced the line `'rewrite' => false,` in the `args`array while declaring the Custom Post Type.

Use this code to solve your problem....Hope this works for you

```
//This function is to register the archive page of post type
function add_rewrite_rules($aRules) {
$aNewRules = array('nos-soins-et-services/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=cpt_soins');
$aRules = $aNewRules + $aRules;
return $aRules;
}
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_rewrite_rules');

//This function is to set your Custom URL Structure and replace it with default structure
function rewrite_flush(){
  global $wp_rewrite;
  $cpt_soins_structure = 'nos-soins-et-services/%cpt_soins%';
    $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag("%cpt_soins%", '([^/]+)', "cpt_soins=");
    $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('cpt_soins', $cpt_soins_structure, false);
  $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
add_action('init','rewrite_flush'
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the default permalink setup. You need to enable URL rewriting with mod_rewrite to get 'pretty' permalinks. Read the codex [permlinks page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) for more info.

Comment: Nope ! I used this one : /%postname%. My rewrite -> slug didn't worked for my custom post type, so I turned it off with false. I know there's a solution like : 

add_action( 'init', 'ss_permalinks' );
function ss_permalinks() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '([^/]+)/all/?',
        'index.php?view=all&service=$matches[1]',
        'top'
);
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'ss_query_vars' );
function ss_query_vars( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars[] = 'view';
    return $query_vars;
}

But I'm a newbie with regex, I don't get the regex code with the add_rewrite_rule() function...

Comment: if flushing the rules doesn't work as Scribu said, there must be an error elsewhere, you certainly should not have to add a rewrite rule manually. post all of your cpt code here so we can have a look.

Comment: `code`
register_post_type('cpt_soins', array( 'label' => 'cpt_soins','description' => 'offres/produits menu Soins & services','public' => true,'show_ui' => true,'show_in_menu' => true,'capability_type' => 'post','hierarchical' => false, `code`

Comment: `code`'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'nos-soins-et-services'),'query_var' => true,'supports' => array('title','editor','excerpt','trackbacks','custom-fields','comments','revisions','thumbnail','author','page-attributes',),'taxonomies' => array('category','post_tag',),`code`

Comment: `code`'labels' => array ('name' => 'cpt_soins','singular_name' => 'cpt_soins','menu_name' => 'Soins & services','add_new' => 'Nouvel article','search_items' => 'Search Soins & services','not_found' => 'Aucun article trouvé','not_found_in_trash' => 'Aucun article dans la poubelle','parent' => 'Parent Soins & services',
),) );`code`

Comment: ok, I set my permalinks to be the same as yours, copied and pasted your code, and created a post. Upon first visit I got a 404, as expected. I visited the permalinks page and saved, then visited again, and got the proper permalink and post. so- your code here works as-is. if it is indeed not the cached rules, your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @Studiomambo: As you can see, code blocks are not meant for comments. Add it to the question instead.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to search the problem elsewhere in my config...